# How to grep using regular expressions contained in dictionaries using Python

Tags: python, regex, bash, associative-array

Currently, I have limitations in bash using `declare -A`, in order to use associative arrays and consider strings as indices, this is because I'm not able to have `v4.0` installed in my environment. As a workaround, I'm trying to construct my script in Python. This is the code I want to translate in Python:

```
declare -A regex
regex[test_one]="line1\|here1"
regex[test_two]="line2\|here2"
regex[test_three]="line3\|here3"
regex[test_four]="line4\|here4"

echo -n "Enter the path to evaluate...> "
read path
for i in "${!regex[@]}"
do
        grep -h -r --color=always "${regex["$i"]}" "$path" >> "$i.txt"
done
```

Any help, will be much appreciated.Thanks

**EDIT NOTE**

This is the piece of code I have currently, thanks to @Harvey

```
import sys
import subprocess

regex = {
'test_one': r'line1\|here1',
'test_two': r'line2\|here2',

}

sys.stdin.flush()
path = raw_input("Enter the path to evaluate...> ") 

search = "/bin/sh -c \'grep -h -r'.split()"
    for name, pattern in regex.items():
        with open('{}.txt'.format(name), 'a') as output:
            cmd = search + [pattern,path] 
        subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=output)
```

But, I have following error in `Line 18`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./Script.py", line 18, in <module>
cmd = search + [pattern,path]
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

Comment: Have you tried to write this in Python? Share your code and specify the problem with it.

Comment: Fix this: `"/bin/sh -c \'grep -h -r'.split()"`. The `.split()` comes after the `"string"`. And get rid of the `/bin/sh` parts. It's unnecessary. Check out the latest code in my answer. It's tested.

Comment: OK!, I changed what you suggested and it worked only when passing a command line argument for example: `./script.py /the/path/to/directory`, however if I run the command without argument I get the following: `path = sys.argv[1]`
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Change it to `if len(sys.argv) >= 2:`

Comment: Thanks!, now works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the best method using only the standard library.

This is for Python 3. For Python 2, change:

- `subprocess.run()` ==> `subprocess.call()`
- `input()` ==> `raw_input()`

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import subprocess

regex = {
    'test_one': r'line1\|here1',
    'test_two': r'line2\|here2',
    'test_three': r'line3\|here2',
    'test_four': r'line4\|here2',
}

if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    path = sys.argv[1]
else:
    path = input("Enter the path to evaluate...> ")

base_cmd = 'grep -h -r --color=always'.split()
for name, pattern in regex.items():
    with open('{}.txt'.format(name), 'a') as output:
        cmd = base_cmd + [pattern, path]
        subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=output)
```

Comment: I'm currently running Python 2.7. I made some changes due to this base on what is supported in this version: First, `path = raw_input()` instead of `path = input()` , then `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.run`, however I'm still not able to make it work as shell prompts the following right after running the script:         `usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]`

Comment: For which invocation of grep? The one where we tell shell to redirect: ":"? Or the one where we capture the output ourselves?

Comment: I have this at the moment:
    `sys.stdin.flush()
    path = raw_input("Enter the path to evaluate...> ") 

    search = "/bin/sh -c \'grep -h -r'.split()"
    for name, pattern in regex.items():
    with open('{}.txt'.format(name), 'a') as output:
    cmd = search + [pattern,path]  <br/>
    subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=output)`

 I have also tried to add `str(search)` but still:
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./Functional_Check_2.py", line 18, in <module>
    cmd = str(search) + [pattern,path]
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`

Comment: I have edit the question with latest code snippets. Thanks